# add a class to an ancer tag on click and save it with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

straight to the point , this is my simple code .

```
 $(".vm-options a").click( function() {
        $(this).addClass("vmselected").siblings().removeClass("vmselected");
    });
```

```
<div class="vm-options">
                <a href="#" class="vm-icon vm-list vmselected" id="list">List view</a>
                <a href="#" class="vm-icon vm-grid" id="grid">Grid view</a>
            </div>
```

now i need it to remember my choices every time i click on 'a href' tag , how can i add cookie to it .

thank you .

Comment: You can start from there: [MDN documentation on cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), or look for [JavaScript cookie libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+cookies+plugin), which might be easier and faster to implement.

Comment: thanks for you respond but i'm quite amateur in JS and need to implement cookie in above script as fast as possible  , but i thank you to show me how can i start learning about it .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Javascript Cooke plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and write `Cookies.set('name', 'value');`

Or the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and write `$.cookie('name', 'value');`

Answer (score 0):

This example uses the [js-cookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), which you'll need to include in your page like so:

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/master/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

You can use it to store and retrieve the ID of the selected link, this way:

```
// Select the currently saved VM at page load
selectVM();

// Do it on click too
$(".vm-options a").click(selectVM);

function selectVM()
{
    var elem = $(this);
    // If the call doesn't come from a click (eg on page load),
    // get the one saved in a cookie or the default one: "#list"
    if(this === window) elem = $('#' + (Cookies.get('selectedVM') || 'list'));

    elem.addClass("vmselected").siblings().removeClass("vmselected");
    // Save it for 7 days
    Cookies.set('selectedVM', elem.id, { expires: 7 });
}
```

Here, the ID is saved in a cookie named `selectedVM` using:

```
Cookies.set('selectedVM', value);
```

and retrieved using:

```
Cookies.get('selectedVM');
```

It's *that* simple!

Comment: thank you again dear blex , now i have something to play with couple hours :D